# How can I get the element visible in the viewport? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of images on a page. As I scroll through the page I would like to show some options in a naviationbar of the image currently in the viewport. Therefore I need to get the image element currently in the viewport, is this possible ?

Jakob

Comment: Anything is possible. http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: Thanks for the comments.. I use the Verge plugin from Ryan Van Etten to check if an element is in the viewport. I can simply check for each image through a list, but it will only work if I know the class and id's of the images. It would be better to get the actual object that is in the viewport...

Comment: Perhaps check the x and y scroll values and use [`document.elementFromPoint(x,y)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.elementFromPoint)? I'm not sure how the cross-browser support is for that, though.

Comment: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Who says there's just one image in viewport? What would you like to do when there are many?

But otherwise you can always get the scroll position of your container with images as well as your images' top offset to see which one is currently in-view.

#### So these values will get you to your result

- container scroll position
- container visible client height
- images' top offset

Using these values will make it possible to locate all images in the view regardless whether they're fully or partially displayed (at the top or bottom).

This is a simplified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yr5PK/) that gives red border around the first *fully-in-the-view* image. The code does this:

```
// get top positions and references to all images
var pos = $("img").map(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  return {
    el: $this,
    top: $this.offset().top
  };
}).get();

// provide document scrolling
$(document).on("scroll", function() {

  $("img").removeClass("first-in-view");

  var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
  var i = 0;
  while(pos[i].top < scroll) i++;

  pos[i].el.addClass("first-in-view");

}).scroll();
```

This should be optimised to only toggle class when it needs to. Otherwise we have flickering in every scroll. But it demonstrates how this can be done and you can get going from here.

#### IMPORTANT

It is utterly important that you attach your image position determining process on **document load** event and not the usually use DOM ready, because you have to wait for the document to load in order for your images to have final positions.

Comment: Great, thanks... that was the solution I was looking for. It wont be a problem with several images in the viewport. Because, as you say, one can just scroll to the image you want to see.